# VB.NET HTTPWEBRESPONSE WebException Work Around

Tags: vb.net, httpwebresponse

Im Trying to Make a Simple Login System using files

```
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Login")
Else

My Code Here
```

But When I Debug it, and test it, it still gives me the 404 error. and not the popup.

is there any other way around this??

EDIT:

Here is My Code

```
        Try
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        MessageBox.Show("Allgood")
    Catch ex As WebException
        If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Login")
        End If
               End Try
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim passcheck As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    Dim pass As String = PasswordTextBox.Text
    If passcheck.Contains(pass) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + UsernameTextBox.Text)
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is throwing a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx), so you need to wrap GetResponse in a Try Catch block and catch the web exception and then display your own dialog.

```
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
Try
    response = request.GetResponse()

    'If it gets here, it did not throw an exception
    MessageBox.Show("It's all good.")
Catch ex as WebException
    If DirectCast(ex.Response, System.Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode  = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Login")
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Can you explain how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Edited my Code into the post.

Comment: is there a way to use webrequest to see if it exists first before it tries getting a response?

Comment: @John: `response` will be useless in the `Catch` block.  The exception that gets thrown, would be thrown before `GetResponse` can return a value to assign to `response`.  You'd need to cast `ex.Response` to a `HttpWebResponse` and get the status code from that.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, ensure that your application is a **Windows Form Application** in the project properties. However as workaround you can use the next code to print it in Visual Studio Output Window.

```
Debug.WriteLine("Invalid Login")
```

To enable the 'Output Window' go to menu 'View' then 'Output' or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Im not quite understanding what your saying?

Comment: Instead of use **MessageBox** just use **Debug.WriteLine** and check the output in Visual Studio.